# Escape awk variables in csh line

Tags: awk, csh

I have this in csh. Let there be files of proper format named fn1_a.dat fn2_a.dat etc.

```
foreach n (a b)
  paste fn1_${n}.dat fn2_${n}.dat | awk '{print $4,$7,($4-$7)}' > new_${n}.dat
end
```

Obviously it does something I don't want. The shell has eaten the $ in the awk command. I've tried with backslash but it failed.

**Update**:

Typo fixed

Purpose of script is to paste two files together line-by-line and have awk print columns 4 and 7 and their difference. Thus i.e. $4 referring in awk to 4th column. But the $ sign is not coming to awk because of the shell.

Yes, I am aware of csh not ideal for script.

Comment: Hopefully you already know this, but all the sane users of `csh` abandoned it in favor of `sh`-compatible shells 30-40 years ago.

Comment: I can't repro. Which dollar sign do you think is being eaten? (How is it obvious that it doesn't do what you want?)

Comment: prlease provide details on what you mean by *`does something I don't want`*?  please update the question with a (small) sample set of input, the (wrong) output generated by your code and the (correct) expected output

Comment: should `fn2_${n}` be `fn2_${n}.dat`?

Comment: If you mean that the awk script is not processing field `$7`, (and hence "eating your `$`s), then double check your data. Does it really have 7 fields (or more), what are you using for the `FS` variable? Good luck.

Answer (score -1):

I set up a simple test file

```
% cat fn1_a.dat
1 2 3 4
```

And copied it over

```
-rw-r--r--   4 x  x     8 Apr 29 09:19 fn1_a.dat
-rw-r--r--   4 x  x     8 Apr 29 09:19 fn1_b.dat
-rw-r--r--   4 x  x     8 Apr 29 09:19 fn2_a.dat
-rw-r--r--   4 x  x     8 Apr 29 09:19 fn2_b.dat
```

Ran a subset of  your code

```
set n = a
paste fn1_${n}.dat fn2_${n}.dat
```

Got reasonable output:

```
1 2 3 4 1 2 3 4
```

Then ran your code

```
% foreach n (a b)
  paste fn1_$? {n}.dat fn2_${n}.dat | awk '{print $4,$7,($4-$7)}'
? end
```

And got the output that seems correct.

```
4 3 1
4 3 1
```

I am using the `csh` I was able to load in current Windows10->WSL2.
I tried getting a more specific version number, but `-v, -V, --version` didn't help )-;

So I recommend that you run the paste command stand-alone

```
set n = a
paste fn1_${n}.dat fn2_${n}.dat
```

And make sure your output is properly ordered.

I guess there is a very slight chance there might be something in pne of `/etc/csh.cshrc`, `/etc/csh.login`,  `$HOME/.cshrc` or `$HOME/.login` env files that could be causing your problem, but I really don't see how it would be possible. I find the `man csh` page confusing regarding these files and there is no way to disable both `.login` and `.cshrc` (at least one of them will be used), so the easiest thing would be to rename these before launching an new `csh` session and running your tests.

Before considering those steps, I would try running your code on a different machine, where hopefully there are no start up files or they are bog standard simple.